# How to read set coordinates for swiping

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
-(void)onTimer{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 100, 200, 200)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    myLabel.text = @"Button1 is in range";
    [myLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    NSLog(@"x=%f",Object1.center.x);
    //position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    //Object1.center = CGPointMake(Object1.center.x,Object1.center.y);

    if((Object1.center.x >341) && (Object1.center.x < 597)){
        [myLabel setHidden:NO];
    }
    else {
        [myLabel setHidden:YES];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
}
```

This is the code I am using now. The x coordinates I get don't change when the object moves. Does anyone know how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This sounds like a question about animation  but there is nothing in your code that moves anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that you're calling the onTimer method *before* the object is moved. Can't tell from the code you've written above, but it'd be worth a shot to check for that.

Maybe you should call this method when the object is done dragging, instead of just when it starts dragging?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
These are the code I left in the viewdidload method. I guess it should read the coordinates every 0.5s and it is printing every 0.5s at the moment.

Comment: In your XIB file, did you say what Object1 is? 

If the object truly is moving, I'd bet you'd see the moved coordinates. It may be that you're moving the object, but the object isn't connected as the "Object1"

Comment: Actually I did it progrmatically instead of using interface builder. These buttons is actually moving along with the scrollview and it is printing a fixed value 551 every 0.5s.